# How to get the curent date with python

Tags: python-3.x, date, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have made a web-scraper with python 3 and bs4. I want the current date so that i can use it as a file name for the scraped website.

**Here is my code:**

```
import bs4
import requests
import sys
import re 
import unicodedata
import os

filename = #Current date#

filename=r"C:\Python\Scripts\Webscrapers\Output\\" +filename+ ".txt"
url = "https://www.wikipedia.org/Example_Article/"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

file = open(filename , 'wb')
for i in soup.select("p"):
    f=i.text
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", f)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
file.close()
```

**After hours of googling i came up with this:**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print (datetime.datetime.today()) 
2020-05-14 11:49:55.695210
>>>
```

But,
I want something like this: 14-May-2020
Is it possible if so, then please help me

I just want to know the current date as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) function from the time module:

```
import time
time.strftime("%d-%B-%Y", time.localtime())

'14-May-2020'
```